# What means “Do I ever get to be upset?~”

Tags: do-support

What means “Do I ever get to be upset? Do I ever get to be anyone but me?”
I have no idea how to use these ‘Do I ever~’ thing...

Comment: To "get to do" something can mean "have the opportunity to do" something, or "be allowed to do" something. "Do I ever get to..." can be a complaining way of saying "I am never allowed to..." , but without some examples from you of text you do not understand, we cannot tell you much.

Comment: The form ***Do I ever get to [verb]?*** is usually a "rhetorical question", where the speaker is complaining that although *others* are able to *[verb]* (or *be verbed*), he never gets a chance to do the same. So OP's example is a fairly unlikely utterance, since most people wouldn't have a problem with not getting upset. There's also the somewhat dated usage *Do you love him? **Do I ever!*** (an exclamation, not a question) which is simply an emphatic agreement *(I really, **really** love him!)*.

Answer (score 3):

"I get to ... [verb]" is an idiom meaning, "I am allowed to ... [verb]".

Derived from that are: "I never get to ... " (I am never allowed to ... "; and "Do I ever get to ... ?" (Am I ever allowed to ... ?)